# Invalid Username/Password when Trying to signup with DRF CreateAPIView

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to create users using django  built-in  "User" Model and with CreateAPIVIew mixin
here is the code :

```
class Register(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny]
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):

        username= request.POST.get('username')
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        # first_name=request.POST.get('first_name')
        # last_name=request.POST.get('last_name')


    user=User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
        # user.first_name='mintu'

        user.save()
```

but when I tried to submit a HTTP post request using Postman 
I have been fired up with an error 
called

```
{
    "detail": "Invalid username/password."
}
```

so to make sure if I my database is creating users perfectly fine 
I have decided to create a user manually through python shell with this command

```
   user=User.objects.create_user('mounikesh','thota@gmail.com','test1234')
```

Successfully a  user has been created

so I came to a conclusion that my database is fine and its accepting the request    now the issue is  only with drf's CreateAPIView
and now I tried to figure if the error is caused because of the data that I've been sending through postman

for that I've directly injected the username,email&password to the server

```
class Register(generics.CreateAPIView):
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny]

        #
        # username= request.POST.get('username')
        # email=request.POST.get('email')
        # password=request.POST.get('password')


        user=User.objects.create_user('ok','ok@gmail.com','test1234')

        # user=User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)

        user.save()
        # token=Token.objects.create(user=user)
        return Response("user has been created")
```

tried to send all my required credentials to create a User expecting my User created response instead got a Error Reponse

tried a lot of searching it in google and all other forums 
But it's of no use

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: what error you've got?

Comment: Invalid Username/Password

Comment: How do you submit the POST request? to which view?

Comment: I added one answer. try that also

Comment: Register is a Class View and using Postman i have fired Post request by providing details (username,email,password) but couldnt create a User

Comment: Where do you get the error message, *Invalid username/password*. Is it from same view?